# Functional interfaces as method parameters

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

After wrting my own generical functional interface and used it with lambdas, I have to use it in a new method that:

- handles a generic array as input, checking that it has a minimum of 4 length
- handles any instance of my functional interface
- handles any instance of a lambda expression, which takes an argument and returns nothing
- applying to the result of your functional interface instance ( here I suppose I have to use a Consumer).

Never using Functional Interfaces before, can someone please explain me how am I supposed to pass 2 functional interfaces as method parameters?

e.g of call:

```
applyTransformations(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4}, add, printer);
```

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunctionalInterface<T> {
    public T doOperation(T param1, T param2, T param3, T param4);
}
```

```
public class Lambdas {
    MyFunctionalInterface<Integer> add = (i1, i2, i3, i4) -> i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;
    MyFunctionalInterface<Integer> multiply = (i1, i2, i3, i4) -> i1 * i2 * i3 * i4;
    MyFunctionalInterface<String> concatenate = (s1, s2, s3, s4) -> s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
    MyFunctionalInterface<String> concatenateWithSpacesBetween = (s1, s2, s3, s4) -> s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s4;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs? What do you want your program to do when received what input?

Comment: Basically the applyTransformations() method takes as parameters a generic array ( it can be of String, Integer etc type), takes any possble instance of my declared Functional Interface-add, multiply for Integers and concatenate for Strings and finally the printer parameter should prints in console the result of the given lambda. So in short, applyTransformations(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4}, add, printer) should display just 10 in console.

Answer (score 3):

> can someone please explain me how am I supposed to pass 2 functional interfaces as method parameters?

Answering this question specifically, you can pass functional interfaces like any other type.

```
private static void printAddAndConcatenate(MyFunctionalInterface<Integer> add, MyFunctionalInterface<String> concatenate) {
    System.out.println(add.doOperation(1, 1, 1, 1));
    System.out.println(concatenate.doOperation("Hel", "lo ", "Wo", "rld"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printAddAndConcatenate(Lambdas.ADD, Lambdas.CONCATENATE);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the simplest of the form, you could represent the function transformation straight forward as :

```
static class Lambdas {
    static MyFunctionalInterface<Integer> add = (i1, i2, i3, i4) -> i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;
    static MyFunctionalInterface<Integer> multiply = (i1, i2, i3, i4) -> i1 * i2 * i3 * i4;
    static MyFunctionalInterface<String> concatenate = (s1, s2, s3, s4) -> s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
    static MyFunctionalInterface<String> concatenateWithSpacesBetween = (s1, s2, s3, s4) -> s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream printer = System.out;
        applyTransformations(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, add, printer);
        applyTransformations(new Integer[]{2, 3, 4, 5}, multiply, printer);
        applyTransformations(new String[]{"one", "day", "or", "another"}, concatenate, printer);
        applyTransformations(new String[]{"yet", "another", "way", "forward"}, concatenateWithSpacesBetween, printer);
    }

    static <T> void applyTransformations(T[] input, MyFunctionalInterface<T> functionalInterface, PrintStream printer) {
        printer.println(functionalInterface.doOperation(input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3]));
    }
}
```

But as you would easily notice, the solution cannot really be extended to have more than 4 elements. Not much to worry though, the developers of the JDK already took care of such simplification and provided a way to operate continuously on a stream of input taking two parameters at a time. All of this directs you towards the use of [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T[])) and further [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) which performs the evaluation on a `BinaryOperator` provided. This reduces your example to

```
static class Lambdas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream printer = System.out;
        applyTransformations(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, Integer::sum, printer);
        applyTransformations(new Integer[]{2, 3, 4, 5}, (a, b) -> a * b, printer);
        applyTransformations(new String[]{"one", "day", "or", "another"}, String::concat, printer);
        applyTransformations(new String[]{"yet", "another", "way", "forward"}, (a, b) -> a + " " + b, printer);
    }

    static <T> void applyTransformations(T[] input, BinaryOperator<T> binaryOperator, PrintStream printer) {
        printer.println(Arrays.stream(input).reduce(binaryOperator));
    }
}
```

On that note, you must be careful of using the operator such as it abides by the following attributes --

> an associative, non-interfering, stateless function for combining two
>   values

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations and very specific code snippets! I was close to your solution, yet I was trying to use Comparator instead of Printstream and got stuck a bit at the generics part...